# Can an objects property, which is a function, be recursively called within itself?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I keep getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: this.setTestType is not a function" when trying to recursively call my setTestType function in my object.

Is recursion not allowed when defining a function as an object property and trying to call itself?

```js
var resultGaAuto = [{
  bestPracticeID: "344033"
}];

var resultAuto = [{
  bestPracticeID: "111111"
}];

var AST = {
  handleSave: function() {
    var data = {};
    var gaRecords = this.processResults(resultGaAuto);
    var autoRecords = this.processResults(resultAuto);
    //console.log(gaRecords);
    //console.log(autoRecords)
    var testTypeGaRecords = this.setTestType(gaRecords, 5);
    var testTypeAutoRecords = this.setTestType(autoRecords, 4);

    console.log(testTypeGaRecords);
    data.records = Object.assign({}, testTypeGaRecords,
      testTypeAutoRecords);
    console.log(data);
  },
  setTestType: function(obj, num) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
      if (key === "testResult") {
        return (obj[key] = num);
      }
      //*******ERROR*******
      return this.setTestType(obj[key], num);
    });
  },
  processResults: function(results) {
    var records = {};
    $.each(results, function(i, result) {
      records[result.bestPracticeID] = records[result.bestPracticeID] || {
        violation: {
          violationID: result.bestPracticeID
        },
        instances: []
      };

      records[result.bestPracticeID].instances.push({
        lineNumber: 1,
        element: "testEl",
        attribute: "testAttr",
        xpath: "testPath",
        testResult: 3
      });
    });

    return records;
  }
};

AST.handleSave();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're not calling it from itself, you're trying to call it inside the `forEach` callback. From which you also cannot `return`, btw - just use a normal loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bound context of your anonymous function should be AST

```
setTestType: function(obj, num) {
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (key === "testResult") {
    return (obj[key] = num);
  }
  //*******ERROR*******
  return this.setTestType(obj[key], num);
}.bind(AST)); // see the bound context!
}
```

Comment: You can also use ES6 arrow functions or try to bind the `this` object

Answer (score 0):

> Can an objects property, which is a function, be recursively called within itself?

Yes. There is no technical limitation here. Just incorrect code.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.setTestType is not a function

`this` is wrong.

## Fix

```
setTestType: function(obj, num) {
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (key === "testResult") {
    return (obj[key] = num);
  }
  //*******FIXED*******
  return AST.setTestType(obj[key], num);
});
},
```

## More

Read up on `this` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this